# Installing .vsix extension for Visual Studio on GitHub Action Server

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions, cicd

I have to deal with .Net 4 legacy project that was poorly maintained and designed. Production deployment consist on installing RazorGenerator .vsix extension to Visual Studio -> compiling project -> manual copying .dll file from bin folder to IIS folder on server.

I want to automatize deployment. I found [Powershell Script](https://gist.github.com/ScottHutchinson/b22339c3d3688da5c9b477281e258400) for installing vsix that I run using command:

> powershell.exe -noexit "& 'D:\a\testtest\testtest\Scripts\install.ps1'"

Unfortunately it freezes at the moment of installing extension on Github Action server.
[image: Moment that GitHub Action Freezes]

I checked script on my desktop and durning "Installing DavidEbbo.RazorGenerator..." User Account Control window appears asking for permission to install this extension so that might be a problem.

Is there any possibility of accepting UAC, turn it off or installing extension on GitHub Action Server?

Comment: FWIW I'm experiencing the same issue trying to install the Multilingual App Toolkit, currently not any closer to a solution besides requesting the folks at GitHub [add the extension](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/new) to their runner image.